# Bash: start date less than equal to end date

Tags: bash, shell, date, while-loop, compare

```
#!/bin/bash
# slightly malformed input data
input_start=2014-11-1
input_end=2016-01-1

# After this, startdate and enddate will be valid ISO 8601 dates,
# or the script will have aborted when it encountered unparseable data
# such as input_end=abcd
startdate=$(date -I -d "$input_start") || exit -1
enddate=$(date -I -d "$input_end")     || exit -1

m="$startdate"
while [ "$m" != "$enddate" ]; do
  echo $m 
  m=$(date -I -d "$m + 1 month")
done
```

"Script is running fine but when I want to change the While loop condition i.e '<=' 'less then or equal to' its giving error even I tried using "-le".What I want to do here is startdate <= enddate in while loop. Can anyone suggest what needs to done to overcome this issue.

[Same Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KCORC.jpg)

Comment: If your script is running fine, then why change it?

Answer (score 6):

`-le` is for numeric data. `2014-11-01` is not a number. Use `<` or `>`. (You need to escape them as `\<` or `\>`. Or use  `[[` instead of `[`.)

effectively, change

```
while [ "$m" != "$enddate" ]; do
```

to

```
until [ "$m" \> "$enddate" ]; do
```

or

```
until [ "$m" '>' "$enddate" ]; do
```

or

```
until [[ "$m" > "$enddate" ]]; do
```

---

Alternately, use `seconds since epoch` instead of `ISO8601` format.

```
while [ "$(date -d "$m" +%s)" -le  "$(date -d "$enddate" +%s)" ]; do
```

Comment: I tried your suggestion but still its not working 
Error:  line 13: [: \<=: binary operator expected

Comment: Above fix works for me. Try adding a `set -vx` at the start of the script and see what arguments are being passed to `[` command.

Comment: Now its giving me result but only showing start date. But rest of the date is not give..like 2014-11-01 2014-12-01 ... till 2016-01-01... I want result like this..

Comment: What I want too do or need ouput like this....
Startdate should to Equal to Enddate output like this
2014-11-1 
2014-12-1
...... 2016-01-1...

Comment: My bad. I did not know that there is no `<=` operator for strings. So, you can use logic as `a<=b` is equivalent to `! (a >b)`. Updated the answer.

Comment: I didn't get you what exactly needs to do here

Comment: There is no `<=` option in `bash` string comparison. So, you can do `while [ ! a '>' b ]`, or equivalently, `until [ a '>' b ]`... See my updated answer.

Answer (score 4):

With [dateutils'](http://www.fresse.org/dateutils/) `datetest` this is simple:

```
$ datetest 2014-11-1 --le 2016-01-1 ; echo $?
0

$ datetest 2014-11-1 --gt 2016-01-1 ; echo $?
1
```

Then again, what you want is simply done by `dateseq`, which also happens to be a tool of the dateutils suite.

```
$ dateseq 2014-11-1 +1mo 2016-01-1
2014-11-01
2014-12-01
2015-01-01
2015-02-01
2015-03-01
2015-04-01
2015-05-01
2015-06-01
2015-07-01
2015-08-01
2015-09-01
2015-10-01
2015-11-01
2015-12-01
2016-01-01
```

Disclaimer: I am the author of the package.